# Flexslider 2 - How to add more transitions using JQuery

Tags: jquery, slideshow, flexslider, transition

I want to find a responsive slider and the best I came across was Flexslider 2. However I also want to implement transition effects like this -> http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

Can anyone advise me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Link to Flexslider 2 -> http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Comment: Just came across this. Don't suppose you found an answer?